# Issues multiplying in python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to make a very simple BTC To USD converter in python (bear with me I'm in the beginning stages), however when I print the value it prints the entered number 275 times (the value of 1 btc). I need it to return the amount entered by the user times 275 (so the user enters 1 and it multiplies 1 by 275 to return 275) Here is my current code:

```
enteramt = raw_input ("How many")
value = enteramt * 275
print ("This is worth" , value)
```

What it prints:
This is worth, 555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555

Except, theres 275 of them, but you get the point

Comment: You need to convert your `raw_input` to an `int`, eg: `enteramt=int(raw_input('How many'))` otherwise, the `*` operator multiplies the string that many times (as you're seeing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 2 `raw_input` returns a string and in python `somestring * value` repeats the string value times. You want to convert the input to an int and then do the multiplication. (you also want to remove the parens from the print, that's a python 3 thing)

```
enteramt = raw_input ("How many")
value = int(enteramt) * 275
print "This is worth" , value
```

In python 3, `raw_input` is replaced by `input`, so you'd write

```
enteramt = input ("How many")
value = int(enteramt) * 275
print("This is worth" , value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `enteramt` is a string. Multiplying a string in python will produce the string repeated. For example:

```
str = '12'
str * 4
>>> '12121212'
```

You should convert your input to float or int:

```
str = float(str)
str * 4
>>> 48.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your raw_input()

So your new code should be like this:

```
enteramt = float(raw_input("How many"))
value = enteramt * 275
print ("This is worth" , value)
```

Or this:

```
enteramt = raw_input("How many")
value = float(enteramt) * 275
print ("This is worth" , value)
```